# Why is type(bytes()) <'str'>

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm fairly new to python and I appreciate it's a dynamic language. Some 30 minutes into my first python code, I've discovered that the `bytes` type behaves a little strange (to say the least):

```
a = bytes()
print type(a)
// prints: <type 'str'>
```

Try it here:
http://ideone.com/NqbcHk

Now, the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/stdtypes.html#bytes-and-byte-array-methods) say `strings` and `bytes` behave very similarly with the exception of `.format` and `.encode` but I didn't expect they were the same type. What I want to ensure is that I get to work with real bytes in my code, and that no coercion/encoding/decoding occurs.

So what's going on here?

Comment: In Python 3, bytes are bytes, not str. You're checking the wrong version :)

Comment: Thanks guys - I'm embarrassed. Should get some coffee before going on :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `bytes` type is new in Python 3.x. In Python 2.x, as a compatibility shim, `bytes` is a simple alias to `str`.

Read more about this here: https://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.6.html#pep-3112-byte-literals

> Python 3.0 adopts Unicode as the language’s fundamental string type
>   and denotes 8-bit literals differently, either as `b'string'` or using a
>   bytes constructor. For future compatibility, Python 2.6 adds bytes as
>   a synonym for the str type, and it also supports the `b''` notation.
>
> The 2.6 str differs from 3.0’s bytes type in various ways; most
>   notably, the constructor is completely different. In 3.0, `bytes([65, 66, 67])` is 3 elements long, containing the bytes representing ABC; in
>   2.6, `bytes([65, 66, 67])` returns the 12-byte string representing the `str()` of the list.
>
> The primary use of bytes in 2.6 will be to write tests of object type
>   such as `isinstance(x, bytes)`. This will help the 2to3 converter, which
>   can’t tell whether 2.x code intends strings to contain either
>   characters or 8-bit bytes; you can now use either bytes or str to
>   represent your intention exactly, and the resulting code will also be
>   correct in Python 3.0.

Answer (score 8):

You're looking at the Python 3 docs. In Python 2, `bytes` is an alias for `str`, added to make it easier to write forward-compatible code (Python 2's `str` is a byte string, while in Python 3 `str` is what was called `unicode` in Python 2).

For more details, see [What’s New In Python 3.0](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#text-vs-data-instead-of-unicode-vs-8-bit).